# Within Karate framework, I want to set the test status as blocked if dependent test fails

Tags: api, automation, karate

We are using Karate framework for api automation, and though not advisable but have a structure in which there are dependent cases In which o/p of one Is passed to other.
So ideally if case 1 fails , case 2 should get blocked as it never ran. An option similar to what we have in ALM for manual case.

Does Karate framework has any such feature or any existing implementation available.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: if the linked answer does not answer your question, assume that this is not supported by karate